# Devise user authentication on Rails 3: routing error on default views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-routing

I followed the basic steps to add authentication to Rails using Devise from [their page](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started), but every time I try to visit a default page (such as the Sign In or Sign Up pages), I get:

---

**Routing Error**

```
No route matches {:controller=>"devise/Home"}
```

---

This happens whether I link to the page in a view using

```
link_to('Register', new_user_registration_path)
```

or just visit "/users/sign_up".

This is a different error from when I visit a page with no route defined (No route matches [GET] "/users/bad_example"), and

```
devise_for :users
```

is already present in my routes.rb.  I have even tried generating views (rails g devise:views) to no avail.  It looks like Devise isn't generating/using a controller or some such.  How do I go about fixing this?

Here are some files that may help:

- [routes.rb](https://github.com/cblair/portal/blob/f-auth/config/routes.rb)
- [rake routes output](https://gist.github.com/1981903)

Comment: Could you post the contents of your routes.rb please?

Comment: Can you post your `rake routes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was not with Devise, but with my routes file.  I have fixed my routes file as seen at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html and now this works properly.

Comment: Can you paste in your new routes and what you changed?